# Replace current process

Tags: process, go

In Ruby, you can use [Kernel.exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) to replace the current executing process by the one triggered.

Is it possible to do the same thing in Go?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the equivalent to Kernel.exec:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "syscall"

func main() {
    if err := syscall.Exec("/bin/ls", []string{"ls", "-l"}, []string{}); err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

but it is not portable.

Comment: How do you handle multiple parameters? I am trying this: `syscall.Exec("/usr/bin/ssh", []string{"-p", "22", "root@host"}, []string{})` but it seems like it's not working, because I am getting the error: `ssh: connect to host 22 port 22: No route to host`

Comment: This works tho: `syscall.Exec("/usr/bin/ssh", []string{"-p 22", "root@host"}, []string{})`

Comment: @kolrie, sorry you need to pass the command name as the first argument. fixed it.

Comment: ah I see. The golang documentation (http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Exec) is really lacking, so out of curiosity how did you find out that the first parameter is the command name?

Comment: I know it from C programming, see: http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve, "By convention, the first of these strings should contain the filename associated with the file being executed...".